# IP based tunneling using putty

Tags: windows, ssh, ip, putty, tunnel

under linux i learnt to establish an ip-based tunnel using ssh, doing this:

```
# background tunnel ip based on tun5
sudo ssh -f -N -w 5:5 root@remoteserver

# setup remote: tun5
ssh root@remoteserver "sudo ip link set tun5 up"
ssh root@remoteserver "ip addr add 10.0.0.100/32 peer 10.0.0.200 dev tun5"

# client setup: tun5
sudo ip link set tun5 up
sudo ip addr add 10.0.0.200/32 peer 10.0.0.100 dev tun5
```

The *-w* parameter empowers me to register a local ip to tun5 device, which in turn becomes my gateway ip to the remote server. Thats pretty awesome with 5 lines of code.

One of the applications i use don't have proper proxy handling and sucks using ssh port tunneling, thats why i need a fully IP-based solution, to get even UDP routed properly.

Any idea how to do this in putty or any other tool under windows?

Any hints highly appreciated!